# Queries and Cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, cursor

Will queries internal having one or more subquery result in cursors at SQL Server level.

In otherwords I am not explicitly using cursors but i have query with a sub query. Now for processing this query will SQL server create cursors internally.

Comment: How are you defining `cursor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sql server do not create any cursotr the subquery. go trough the below link for more details

There are two kinds of subqueries: 
**standard** and **correlated**. The standard subquery executes once, and its results are fed into the parent query. A correlated subquery executes once for every row retrieved by the parent query. In this tip, I shed some light on the power of nested subqueries (I'll save correlated subqueries for another day).

[Subquery Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252(SQL.80).aspx)

[Working with nested subqueries in SQL Server](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6154142.html)